# How can I clearly indent an XML file and keep good coding practices?

Tags: xml

I'm currently writing an XML file to hold strings for translation, but I'm trying to polish it for better readability and I'd like to space it so I can easily read and edit it. I want to try to stick to better coding practices however so I'm wondering what the best way to do it is.

This is a chunk of my XML at the moment.

```
    <string name="Russian_lang">???<!-- (Ruština) --></string>
    <string name="Turkish_lang">Türkçe<!-- (Turečtina) --></string>
    <string name="Chinese_Simplified_lang">???<!-- (Čínština  - Zjednodušená) --></string>
    <string name="Chinese_Traditional_lang">???<!-- (Čínština  - Tradiční) --></string>
```

I had a guess and figured this might do it? But it looks wrong to me . I feel there is a better way to do it, but I don't often use XML files so I don't really know.

```
    <string name="Russian_lang"             >???<!--    (Ruština)                   --></string>
    <string name="Turkish_lang"             >Türkçe<!-- (Turečtina)                 --></string>
    <string name="Chinese_Simplified_lang"  >???<!--    (Čínština  - Zjednodušená)  --></string>
    <string name="Chinese_Traditional_lang" >???<!--    (Čínština  - Tradiční)      --></string>
```